# How to run .rdp file in Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, rdp

I have installed **Microsoft Remote Desktop 8.0.5 For MAC OSX** 10.8.5 and added new remote connection in the list which works fine.
Now i export same connection to .rdp file but when i execute it mstsc opens remote os login screen and asks for user password to login (which is already in keychain store).

- how can i launch .rdp file so that it will not ask remote user password?
- where/how to store password?

-------  .RDP File ----------

```
screen mode id:i:0
use multimon:i:1
session bpp:i:32
full address:s:192.168.1.130
audiomode:i:0
username:s:mylabs\administrator
disable wallpaper:i:0
disable full window drag:i:0
disable menu anims:i:0
disable themes:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
authentication level:i:0
connect to console:i:0
gatewayusagemethod:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:1
allow desktop composition:i:1
bookmarktype:i:3
use redirection server name:i:0
```

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me
https://serverfault.com/questions/962628/failure-connecting-to-a-cyberark-managed-server-using-macos

Use Microsoft RDP Client for Mac starting from version 10.2.2
Run the following command on the Mac Terminal

```
defaults write com.microsoft.rdc.macos ClientSettings.EnforceCredSSPSupport 0
```

Close terminal and try to connect